# Wordpress hacked: added site.xml and /good directory

Tags: xml, wordpress, security, sitemap, ads

I'm working on a wordpress website which's been hacked.
At a first look I saw a site.xml file and a /good directory placed i nthe root directory of the website.

site.xml contains these header strings:

```
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"><url>
  <loc>http://www.casadellavita.com/good/ray-ban-outlet-nj.html</loc>
<lastmod>2015-06-01T08:10:43+02:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
```

and then a huge list of these elements like:

```
<url>
<loc>http://www.thehackedwebsite.com/good/ray-ban-3404-sale.html</loc>
<lastmod>2015-06-01T08:10:43+02:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
```

In the /good directory I found a huge list of files like "buy-ray-ban-58014.php" containing a lot of advertising text.

What's that?
I will remove site.xml and the /good irectory but how can I fix this hack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At First step you can use Website Vulnerability scanners like Acunetix 
you can scan every website with this software and it advise you how to fix bugs.

but there is another good option for wordpress websites:
you can us "wpscan" tool in linux base system for advanced wordpress scan.
wpscan.org/

Comment: Thank you so much! It's a precious infomation